# net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE.NotSameOrigin Instagam Scraping

Tags: javascript, jquery, instagram, instagram-api

I am making a website (static) and I use https://rapidapi.com/Prasadbro/api/instagram-stories1/ API to get the video URL this the URL

https://scontent-jnb1-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/e15/242204298_1728375270686500_5634415857798350440_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-jnb1-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=104&_nc_ohc=3O8LpuGJsdUAX_E1Dxz&edm=AHlfZHwBAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=0a22779e81f47ddb84155f98f6f5f75f&oe=6148F26D&_nc_sid=21929d

this is the HTML

```
<video width="342" height="608" src="https://scontent-jnb1-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/e15/242204298_1728375270686500_5634415857798350440_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-jnb1-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=104&_nc_ohc=3O8LpuGJsdUAX_E1Dxz&edm=AHlfZHwBAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=0a22779e81f47ddb84155f98f6f5f75f&oe=6148F26D&_nc_sid=21929d"></video>
```

I see the image when I go to the URL, directly through the browser. But it is not showing up on my website

When I checked the Debug Console I get this error.

`net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE.NotSameOrigin`

I googled and also checked StackOverflow for this error but their answers are based on PHP, mine is a static website based on Javascript and jQuery. Please Help